# Crashlytics customkey reporting when crashing

Tags: android, crashlytics

When using customkey with the following

```
  Crashlytics.setString(item.first,item.second);
```

I can retrieve those key values back in the console (Non Fatal) when using

```
  Crashlytics.logException(e);
```

But for crash session (fatal ) ,self sent by Crashlytics  I can NOT  see any log , key / value . I can  only see the stack trace , and all device information ... key /value are empty :(

Answer (score 1):

Open your crash and click the "[View all sessions](http://joxi.ru/xAe0LeNSp0bnD2)" button 
and you see all your [custom keys](http://joxi.ru/eAO1L40IxJ6oym)